# Lightbox to implement album in a web application

Tags: integration, cross-browser, lightbox, web-applications

We are trying to implement a lightbox based album viewer in our web application. However, we are struggling to get it working for IE. Can you please suggest the remedy? It would be great if you can suggest some other alternatives for implementing the picture slide show for album too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) is a jQuery plugin similar to lightbox. Works with IE and supports different media in the dialog (e.g. videos, ajax calls)

Answer (score 1):

[Slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox) claims to have IE6 compatibility. I don't have access to an IE6 machine to test today but it might be worth checking out their demo page.

Comment: Hello Brian,

I tried it on IE and it appears to work but we are still facing problem with overlay. We are not getting that dark background. Can you please help here?

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of scripts like lightbox is that you can write the page to work on really old browsers, then the script just makes it work much better. Your page should already work before you add the lightbox script (i.e. the thumbs should already link to the full size image, or open it in a new window).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [lightbox2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) and then there is [jQuery Popeye](http://dev.herr-schuessler.de/examples/jquery-popeye/) what is IMHO by far better. Check out a demo installation [here](http://dev.herr-schuessler.de/examples/jquery-popeye-1-0/).